# Assigning a value to a node in a ZEST graph

Tags: java, graph, zest

Is there a way to assign a value to a specific node in a graph built in JAVA using the ZEST API?

Given a graph node "p", I thought p.setData(value) would work. I tried this, but it didn't really work out.

Comment: In what way did it not work out?

Comment: So you set something with `setData()` and then `getData()` returns null? I gave it a quick try and it works for me. Perhaps if you posted a snippet of what you are doing and the Zest version you are using we can see what's wrong here...

Answer (score 0):

There isn't in the actual API since LayoutEntity is an interface.  You need to know which type of nodes (LayoutEntity) you're working with first and determine if that class that implements LayoutEntity has such a field.  You can just create a HashMap to index the layoutEntities (aka nodes) of your graph, when you initially create your list of nodes (LayoutEntity objects).  That way you can come back to them later, after you have the X/Y coordinates.

This code will get you started.

```
org.eclipse.zest.layouts/src/org/eclipse/zest/layouts/exampleUses/SimpleSwingExample.java

org.eclipse.zest.layouts/src/org/eclipse/zest/layouts/exampleUses/SimpleSWTExample.java
```